# Erro Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estou tentando compilar meu projeto no Xamarin Forms e esta dando esse erro:

```
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro        ***Falha inesperada da tarefa "Aapt".***
System.AggregateException: Um ou mais erros. ---> System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CalculateVersionCode(String currentAbi, String versionCodePattern, String versionCodeProperties)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.GenerateCommandLineCommands(String ManifestFile, String currentAbi, String currentResourceOutputFile)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.DoExecute(ITaskItem manifestFile, ParallelLoopState state, Int32 loop)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<ForEachWorker>b__3(Int32 i, ParallelLoopState state, TLocal local)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](TSource[] array, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func`1 localInit, Func`4 body, Action`1 localFinally)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.Execute()
   em Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   em Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
---> (Exceção Interna N° 0) System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CalculateVersionCode(String currentAbi, String versionCodePattern, String versionCodeProperties)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.GenerateCommandLineCommands(String ManifestFile, String currentAbi, String currentResourceOutputFile)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Aapt.DoExecute(ITaskItem manifestFile, ParallelLoopState state, Int32 loop)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<ForEachWorker>b__3(Int32 i, ParallelLoopState state, TLocal local)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   em System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )<---  AppRDVAUX.Android
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar a solucionar?

@edite

```
2>    AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths:  (TaskId:495)
```

2>    LibraryProjectJars:  (TaskId:495)
2>    ExtraArgs: --no-version-vectors (TaskId:495)
2>    CreatePackagePerAbi: False (TaskId:495)
2>    ResourceNameCaseMap: layout\Tabbar.axml|layout\tabbar.xml;layout\Toolbar.axml|layout\toolbar.xml;drawable\LogoAntigoAraguaina.png|drawable\logoantigoaraguaina.png;drawable\DevByAcesso.png|drawable\devbyacesso.png;drawable\IconAraguaina.png|drawable\iconaraguaina.png;drawable\Araguaina240360.jpg|drawable\araguaina240360.jpg; (TaskId:495)
2>    VersionCodePattern: {abi}{versionCode:D5} (TaskId:495)
2>    VersionCodeProperties:  (TaskId:495)
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1942,3): error MSB4018: Falha inesperada da tarefa "Aapt".
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1942,3): error MSB4018: System.AggregateException: Um ou mais erros. ---> System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.

Comment: Verifica a versão do Java, do Android SDK, Windows e Visual Studio.

Comment: Ola Tony, o Android sdk é o 25, o Java é o 8, windows 10 e visual studio 2017. O meu aplicativo estava rodando numa boa, então eu coloquei uma imagem nele (imagem sem caracteres especiais) e ele continuou compilando, só que do nada ele começou a dar esse erro. Vi em outro tópico um cara ensinando a pegar o erro mais detalhadamente, vou editar o post e colocar o que achei.

Comment: Será que é algo relacionado ao formato / opções usadas quando foi gerado este arquivo PNG ? Você testou com outro arquivo ?

Comment: Não testei com outro arquivo ainda, vou tentar.

Comment: Exclui todos os arquivos (resoucers) do meu projeto e compilei novamente, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você deve ter alterado as propriedades do projeto android. Especificamente a o campo `Version Number`, deve estar com um conteúdo inválido, que não consegue converter para numérico. Acho que sua intenção era alterar o `Version Name`. Dá uma conferida lá.

Comment: Olá, era exatamente isso, depois de procurar bastante apenas alterei o numero da versão no Android Manifest, recompilei e acabou o erro.

Comment: @Q.Wesley Beleza. Registrei como resposta para a posteridade =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o erro **não está** relacionado à versão do Java, SDK ou aos seus recursos de imagem como sugerido nos comentários...

Você deve ter alterado as propriedades do projeto android. Especificamente a o campo `Version Number` deve estar com um conteúdo inválido, que não pode ser convertido para numérico.

> System.AggregateException: Um ou mais erros. ---> System.FormatException: **A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.**
>      ...
>      em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.**CalculateVersionCode**(String currentAbi, String versionCodePattern, String versionCodeProperties)

Acho que sua intenção era alterar o `Version Name`.

Dá uma conferida lá nas propriedades do projeto ou no `manifest` e corrige isso que volta a compilar.

Espero que isso ajude.